# How do I compare classes using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to determine the class type of a class using reflection and then do something specific. For example, if the class is a double, use a double specific method.

I am attempting to use

```
  if(f.getClass() == Double.class)
```

However, I am getting a compiler error:

"Incompatible operand types Class <capture#1-of ? extends Field> and Class<Double>"

What is the proper way to do this?

Edit: to be more clear

f is of type Field. obtained by reflection in a loop

```
  (Field f : instance.getDeclaredFields())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting error message (I didn't know '==' operator would check those).
But based on it, I suspect that your comparison is wrong: you are trying to see if Field class (theoretically its super-class, but only in theory -- Field is final) is same as Double.class, which it can not be.

So: yes, comparison should work, iff you give it right arguments. So I suspect you want to do:

if (f.getType() == Double.class)

instead. And that should work, given that Double is a final class. Otherwise "isAssignableFrom" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If you have objects then use

```
if (f instanceof Double) { }
```

Another interesting thing is method isAssignableFrom:

```
if (f.getClass().isAssignableFrom (Double.class)) { }
```

But in general it's a bad style. Use polymorphism to implement logic which depends on class types.

---

Answer for comment:  f instanceof Double works fine.

You probably wrote something like this:

```
float f = 1.1f;
if (f instanceof Double) { ..}
```

And smart java compiler says that you've got CE. BUT:

```
public static boolean isInstanceOfDouble (Object obj) {
   return obj instanceof Double;
}

psvm (String [] args) {
   sout (isInstanceOfDouble (1.1f);
}
```

..this works fine

Comment: That's not always the same thing. If Double weren't a final class, the two would be different if f happened to be a subclass.

Comment: Yes, as you can see I wrote "interesting", it means "read javadocs for more details".
Anyway I prefer OOP solutions

Comment: Heh, +1 for the 'psvm' and 'sout' live templates.  If only someone would build a textbox control with code completion...

Comment: You isInstanceOfDouble() example works fine because of auto-boxing and is highly contrived.  Why would I ever want to see if a primitive type is an instance of any object, when it is by definition not?  (It's wrapper might be but that's not the same).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be

```
if (f.getClass().equals(Double.class))
```

**Edit:** Ah, now I see the problem. The error you were getting was because (as a result of generics) the compiler could tell that the classes would never be equal (`Field.class` cannot equal `Double.class`). Using .equals() turns it into a warning instead of an error, but it's still wrong code.

`Field.getType()` gives you the type of the field. Since this cannot be known at compile time, you will not get an error if you use the `==` operator as you did originally.

Comment: This does not work the way I would like. Thanks for the help, I stumbled across the answer and have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using getType() to get the underlying type, not get class.
getType() returns the class of the underlying type as required.

the code looks like this:

```
  if(f.getType().equals(Double.class))
```

Comment: That's the answer to a completely different question. getType() is specific to the Field class, while getClass() applies to all objects.

Comment: But did you notice that both Roman and I gave answers that didn't make sense? We were both answering your original question. (I've updated my answer to explain the real issue here.)

Comment: I admit the first question probably wasn't as clear as it should have been, however I clearly mentioned reflection both in the question and in my post explaining the question. Additionally, I don't see why my answer is downvoted as it clearly answers my question...

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet should work perfectly:

```
if (f.getType() == Double.TYPE)
```

BTW, neither `==` nor `equals` works for **Number** types according to my test (JRE7)